# issues deploying solidity smart contract to rinkeby test network

Tags: deployment, ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

I'm using openZeppelin to make a crowdsale contract, all (30 of them) my tests pass with flying colours ;) and I can migrate on a locall ganache blockchain no problem.

1. When I try to deploy to rinkeby I start having issues. My config in truffle.js is

```js
rinkeby: {
  provider: rinkeybyProvider,
  network_id: 3,
  gas: 4712388,
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("40", "gwei"),
  websockets: true,
  from: "0x9793371e69ed67284a1xxxx"
}
```

When I deploy on rinkeby I get:

> "SplitWallet" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its
> constructor. Try:    * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy
> all require conditions.    * Adding reason strings to your require
> statements.

I have gone through and put messages in every revert in the constructor hierachy, but I never see any of the messages. I thought it might be that my payees and shares were different lengths but, no, they are the same (only parameters that the constructor for a splitwallet take)

Things to note:

- I have an Infura API key
- I am using `truffle-wallet-provider` provider, with just a private key (no mnemonic) to deploy
- I am confused (due to the above), how my deploy script, can know multiple (10) wallets on deployment. Usually (in Ganache) these are the 10 wallets Ganache generates for you, but here, I am providing a private key, so it shouldn't be able to know 10 wallets, just one - the public key of the private key that is deploying the contract, no? (talking about here):

```js
module.exports = async (
  deployer,
  network,
  [owner, purchaser, investor, organisation, ...accounts] //how does it know these??
)
```

This last point makes me wonder, because I printed out owner/purchaser and they don't match my public key wallet at all, so I have no idea where they are coming from. And if they don't match, and it defaults to the owner being accounts[0], then that wallet may not be able to pay for the gas... perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rinkeby network id is 4, not 3.